# Как узнать, сколько прогонов совершено по правилам htaccess (для конкретного запроса)?

Tags: .htaccess, apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-redirect

Столкнулся с проблемой.

У меня в htaccess есть кусок кода:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !^$
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

Этот кусок кода служит для того, чтобы прогон по всем правилам внутри htaccess проводился только один раз. Этот код упоминается на разных ресурсах. На стаке его тоже часто приводят.

Этот кусок кода работает очень странно. Такое ощущение, что он ВСЁ-ТАКИ позволяет сделать **второй** прогон по правилам. А **третий** уже не позволяет.

На всякий случай: у меня Apache 2.2.22

**Вопрос:**
Как узнать, сколько прогонов совершено по правилам htaccess (для конкретного запроса)?

Comment: `LogLevel rewrite:trace3` -> после этого в error log увидите все преобразования, в т.ч. пометку `redir#N`, где `N` будем номером обработки. [L] Сам по себе запрещает дальнейшие применения правил, но результат работы mod_rewrite - новый (внутренний) запрос, который снова прогоняется через все правила, описанные в .htaccess.

Comment: @Etki А что это за команда? Где её вводить? У меня сайт на Shared хостинге. Я не имею прямого доступа к Apache. Как быть? error log - это тот, что в корне сайта?